# If data already exists, I need to update it and add old values and new values in some column, but it was showing syntax error in line 8

Tags: sql, triggers

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `common`.`material_reservation_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `material_reservation` FOR EACH ROW

 IF EXISTS (SELECT Reservation_DATE,Item_Number , OU_Organization_Id , INV_Organization_Id FROM common.material_onhand WHERE 
        (Transaction_DATE=NEW.Reservation_DATE  AND Item_Number=NEW.Item_Number AND OU_Organization_Id=NEW.OU_Organization_Id AND INV_Organization_Id=NEW.INV_Organization_Id))
    THEN
        UPDATE common.material_onhand SET Onhand_Quantity = Onhand_Quantity + NEW.Quantity,  Reserved_Quantity = Reserved_Quantity +  NEW.Quantity
        WHERE (Onhand_Quantity=NEW.Quantity AND Reserved_Quantity=NEW.Quantity)
   END IF;
```

but it was showing the error in line no 8

Comment: [`SQL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) is a query language. Each database vendor has its own dialect of SQL, and they're not always interchangeable. To answer your question, we need to know what kind of database you're using (Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, Postgres, MySQL, etc.) Please use the `edit` button under your question and add the appropriate database tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which RDBMS you are using but in SSMS the update statement would need aliases when two or more tables are involved.

Look:

```
UPDATE t
set t.onhand_quantity = t.onhand_quantity + i.quantity,
t.reserved_quantity = t.reserved_quantity + i.quantity
from your_table t inner join inserting_values_table i
on t.onhand_quantity = i.quantity and t.reserved_quantity = i.quantity
```

Listen to me, it's really difficult to answer if you use those strange aliases and you don't write in a more readable way.